# Use a different JAVA_HOME when running JUnit through Ant

Tags: junit, ant, junit4, java-home

Currently, I am running Junit from Ant.

My environment variable JAVA_HOME is set to `/path-to-jdk6` but I want the JUnit tests to run with `/path-to-jdk8`.

How do I set that?

This is my Ant target:

```
<target name="junit" depends="compile">
  <junit printsummary="yes"
       haltonfailure="no">
    <classpath> <path refid="sample-classpath" /> </classpath>
    <formatter type="plain" usefile="false" />
    <batchtest todir="${junit.report.dir}">
      <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}">
        <include name="**/*Test.class" />
      </fileset>
    </batchtest>
  </junit>
</target>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you do not close the **target tag** ? **</target>**. Are you really asking how to set an environmental variable ? The OS you are using would be useful in that case.

Comment: @JonGoodwin Formatting issue. Added closing target. I am using linux here. and ant version is 1.8.1

Answer (score 1):

You could wrap your JUnit task in a separate Ant [exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) like so:

```
<macrodef name="exec-junit">
    <attribute name="antfile" default="${ant.file}" />
    <sequential>
        <exec executable="ant">
            <env key="JAVACMD" value="/path/to/jvm/1.8/bin/java" />
            <arg line='-f "@{antfile}"' />
            <arg line="junit" />
        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

This uses the [`JAVACMD`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/running.html#envvars) environment variable ...

> **JAVACMD** - full path of the Java executable. Use this to invoke a different JVM than JAVA_HOME/bin/java(.exe).

The above target can then be invoked like so:

```
<target name="test">
    <exec-junit/>
</target>
```

Comment: Why is there no executable tag like javac provides it? This makes it a lot more complex :(